# Как получить cookie с конкретным именем?

Tags: javascript, cookie

У меня есть кука "cart". Я бы хотел вытащить ее при помощи document.cookie, но он вытаскивает все куки сразу. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: фильтруйте просто

Comment: только руками разбирать строку

Comment: Ну [например](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie#getcookie-name)